Achieving parallelism with multiprocessing on batches of data
I have data that I want to preform a batched process on using two GPUs in parallel, so I wrote the following worker class:
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, gpu_id: int, res_queue: multiprocessing.Queue(), class_func: GPUFanc):
        super().__init__()
        self.gpu_id = gpu_id
        self.func = class_func
        self.res_queue = res_queue

    def run_func(self):
        with cp.cuda.Device(self.gpu_id):
            self.res_queue.put(self.class_func.run_func(self.batch))

   def alloc_batch(self, batch):
       with cp.cuda.Device(self.gpu_id):
           self.batch = cp.asarray(batch)

So I'm putting the results into a queue to deal with later, and the way that I initialize and run those workers is:
queue_list = [multiprocessing.Queue() for i in range(num_gpus)]
workers = []
for i in range(num_gpus):
    workers.append(Worker(gpu_ids[i], queue_list[i], func_class_object)

for worker in workers:
    worker.start()

for num_batch in range(num_batches):
    main_batch = get_batch(num_batch)  # Gives some arbitrary batch of data
    
    divided_batches = devide_batch(main_batch, num_gpus)
    
    for worker_ind in range(len(workers)):
        workers[worker_ind].alloc_batch(divided_batches[worker_ind])
    
    for worker in workers:
        worker.run_func()

# ------ Take out all the batches results from queues after the for loop ------

and then I'm calling worker.join().
My questions is does the two processes run in parallel when I'm calling the "worker.run_func()" inside the for loop or the call waits for the run_func to finish in every iteration.
If it isn't in parallel what changes I need to make to achieve it.
Also when looking with "nvidia-smi -l 1" I can see that the GPUs work one after the other according to the utilization section.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

I'm not sure but as for me you should first set all parameters in Worker and later execute .start(). And you should put code in def run() instead of def run_func() - because when you run .start() then it creates new process and it executes code in worker.run() which runs in separated process. Other functions run in current process (without parallelism). At this moment you run .start() which runs nothing and it finish process and later you runs normal functions in single process - so they runs one after another.

if you want to work in batch then run() should rather run while-loop which checks if there is new data in queue, executes code, puts result back in queu, and it waits for new data in queue. I'm not sure if you doesn't need two queues - one to send data to process, and other to get data from process.

Thank you for those comments, maybe the function should be executed in def run() and check if there is new data coming in with the usage of while and queue, and the outer for loop only puts data inside the workers. But inside the worker’s while loop if the input time of data is smaller then the function run time should I put an if statement somewhere? @furas

while can use  queue.is_empty() to check if there is new data and next use with queue.get()to get it and run function with new data. OR maybe you should usepoolinmultiprocessing - and it will execute the same function with new data when it finish with previous data.
